# Django Templates: How to show the time differences between a Datastore time and current time?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am working on a django- Google app engine project. A user inserts some value and the datetime field is auto filled using google app engine DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True) property. Now, I have to display on the template the difference of this time and the current time when the user is viewing the result.

For e.g. if the inserted time was 5:00 and the user is viewing the post at 6:00, the result should be 1 hour. Is there any builtin filter available with the Django templates to perform the same? I tried timesince as:

```
{{ topic.creation_date| timesince: now }}
```

where creation_date is a datetime field. But its not working.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you have a variable called "now" in your context? If not, that will fail.

However, you don't actually need one, because if you call the `timesince` filter without an argument, it will use the current time. So just do:

```
{{ topic.creation_date|timesince }}
```

Comment: Didn't know it. Thanks a lot Daniel.

Comment: However, "now" does work without passing with context. It was just not working with "timesince". Because it was working fine as {% now "jS F Y H:i" %} for me.

Comment: Completely different thing. That's using the default built-in template *tag*, `{% now %}`, rather than using the value of `now` as a variable.

Comment: Restart your server if you are experiencing problems, worked for me. thx

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use time.time()? And for creation date you first have to insert given row into database. That means you can read it.

```
from datetime import timedelta

yourmodel.save()

cdate= yourmodel.creation_date

seconds = time.time() - time.mktime(cdate.timetuple())
timediff = str(timedelta(seconds=seconds))
```